# Force Youtube Caption to OFF

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video, youtube

I have an embed URL of a youtube video, where I am setting **cc_load_policy=0** to force it to **DO NO** display captions. What happening is, captions are still being displayed on the video from Youtube.

### Steps to Reproduce

1. Go to the URL => https://www.youtube.com/embed/1u_QKOrXyMM?controls=0&wmode=transparent&rel=0&showinfo=0&enablejsapi=1&modestbranding=1&cc_load_policy=0&html5=1&widgetid=1
2. Verify the above URL has **cc_load_policy=0**
3. Click on the video and press **C**. Captions can be Turned ON/OFF by pressing C over again. Toggle the captions to be turned **ON.**
4. Go to the Video URL again with **cc_load_policy=0**

### Expected

Captions should not be displayed as **cc_load_policy=0**

### Observe

Captions are still displayed even forcing **cc_load_policy=0**

Answer (score 0):

The captions depend on users own preferences not by the developers preference.

> Setting the parameter's value to 1 causes closed captions to be shown by default, even if the user has turned captions off. The default behavior is based on user preference.

You can read more about it here:[Youtube IFrame player API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters)